# What color is Icon 117

Tags: color-mania

In Color Mania (similar to iconmania but rather than spell it out you have to guess the colors that make it up) I'm stuck on an icon.  Every time I run out of lives I have to wait an hour to get more, so I'd rather not have to keep guessing.

I'm in level 6 (Icon 117) but I'm not sure if icons always go in the same order.  I'm also not even going to attempt describing the picture, so here is a screenshot:

[image]

I tried Google's "Search by Image" feature, but couldn't find the answer that way either.

Comment: You realize there is a color gradient in there?  And a color gradient isn't a single color.  I see at least two different shades of gray, and black.  Are you leaving out any details?  How about a link to the game maker's site?  Or instructions on how to play the game?  The image looks like a sword on a sharpening stone.

Comment: @BonGart I'm not seeing a color gradient.  The point of the game is to figure out the colors that make up different images (logos, characters, etc.)  The first time you come to a new image, it is in grey-scale.  As you pick the correct colors, the image is colored with the option you picked in the sections it is of that color.  The link is in the wiki for the tag, but here it is: http://www.colormaniaapp.com/

Comment: From what I see, the darker gray section of the image that looks like a blade, is divided at the top.  That division fades on the right side of the division.  Here.... http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/104/hrob.jpg see?

Comment: @BonGart Yes that is called grey-scale, meaning the only colors are white, black, and all the shades of grey between them.  When you say "Color Gradient" it made me think of something, well, not grey.  I also thought it looked like a sword, but I have no idea what color it would be, since swords are usually not of a certain color.

Comment: I'm sorry the more generic "color gradient" term confused you.  In point of fact, "Gray Scale" is not the gradual shifting from one gray to another.  "Gray Scale is a term that describes a palette of different shades of Gray http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale so that fading, or color shift, is *not* called Gray Scale.  You could use Gray Scale to describe the entire image (the picture before you pick a color is in gray scale), but not that fading effect.  And maybe you aren't supposed to color the sword, but the object it is against... the black thing.

Comment: @BonGart Informative.  As a programmer I have rather little knowledge of anything design related, especially colors. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error, the answer ended up being Yellow.  The picture was a Kill Bill reference.

[image: Answered]